Lost on a geocaching cipher puzzle (Canada): ZEEE VWNI
When I asked for some help, people said this was a rail fence cipher.... still no help. Below is the code to decipher:
ZEEE VWNI NEVI FEUH EREN NOTL FEOE VIFE VIFR RZOV NENW VITO FENI FEVO TEES EI
Source: https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC1AH3A

Look into columnar transposition. Given that you tagged this [geocaching] the resulting string of numbers might be a coordinate for latitude/longitude/both

I've looked up the source. It's a regular geocache (not Premium), active since 2008 so no current prize attached (found 30 times in all). Coordinates of the cache posting (so not the final answer, but it will be nearby) are N 50° 02.429 W 110° 41.609 in Alberta, Canada.

If you split the text in three approximately equal "fence rails", and read vertically "along the fence posts"

 
 ZEEEVWNINEVIFEUHERENN
 OTLFEOEVIFEVIFRRZOVNE
 NWVITOFENIFEVOTEESEI
 

you get

 zone twelve five two one five nine five five five four three zero seven nine


 I don't know what the "Zone Twelve" refers to but 5215955543079 is probably a lat and long. Not clear where the split is, it could be 52.1595, 55.43079 which is in Russia.

After some Googling and the comment indicating it's in

 Canada,

I suspect it refers to this?

 https://epsg.io/32612

But I can't make the numbers convert to a co-ordinate in that zone.
Further edit:
Oh no, the geocache page now linked in the puzzle says it's in Medicine Hat, which is apparently

 divided into Zones. Zone 12 is the south east of the map: https://www.medicinehat.ca/en/roads-parking-and-transportation/resources/Documents/Street-Sweeping-Map.pdf

Again, still not sure how to convert the numbers into coordinates though.
Thanks to the comment from daw,

 treating the string as WGS/UTM results in
 12N 521595 5543079
 which is decimal degrees is N 50.039616 E -110.698428
 which is indeed in Medicine Hat.


 


rot13(Artngvat gur ybatvghqr yrnqf gb na nern whfg bss gur pbnfg bs Pnanqn.)

rot13(pbaireg gur ahzoref gb gur jtf/hgz sbezng)

Just wanted to say thank you to those who helped out on this. Was on the right track, but still completely lost. I got the zone 12, which totally threw me.  So thanks again, just made find 3000.

@user93230 Congratulations on your landmark find! Glad we could help. Happy caching :)

I edited your post to show how to manually decode the cipher, please feel free to revert or re-edit as you see fit. (Oh, if this site only had some kind of a "suggest edit" functionality..)

@Bass you could create an extra low-rep account just to suggest edits, if you like. (As long as you don't then approve your own edits). Keep it under 2k rep and all its edits need to be approved first.

@Bass thanks for the edit, looks good to me!
